# Angular 6 routing redirect not redirecting properly

Tags: javascript, angular

When I go to localhost:4200, I'm expecting to be directed to `AboutComponent` (on the `/home` path),  and am also expecting `/home` to be appended to the URL, but instead I'm getting redirected to the `PageNotFoundComponent`, and `/home` is not being appended to the URL. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { SignupComponent } from '../signup/signup.component';

const routes: Routes = [
 {path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
  {path: '' , redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

import { AdminModule } from './admin/admin.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AboutModule } from './about/about.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AboutModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
    declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],

  providers: [CookieService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(router: Router) {

  }
}
```

about-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutComponent } from './about.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from '../page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

const aboutRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'home', component: AboutComponent}
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(aboutRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AboutRoutingModule { }
```

about.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AboutRoutingModule } from './about-routing.module';
import { AboutComponent } from './about.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AboutComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AboutRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class AboutModule { }
```

Comment: That's the way the router behaves . you've not defined ``/home`` route and since it is not defined , ``PageNotFoundComponent`` is loaded

Comment: @Crowdpleasr https://stackblitz.com/angular/pbrvgeyeqob I can see that works !

Comment: try by changing the pathMatch: 'full' into pathMatch: 'prefix' .The problem is may be the router is not getting the correct path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App-routing module is the parent whereas about-routing module is child, So when you will get triggered with '/home' you need to tell the parent to load the child routes that will be done like

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
 {path: '' , redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
 {
  path: 'home',
  loadChildren: './About/about.module.ts#AboutModule'
 },
 {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}

];
```

when we will provide 'loadChildren' in routes, then the parent will load the child module(About module), and routes forchild is called, then will work.

why it is failing because there no route is mentioned for '/home' in parent so it choose the

```
{path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
```

so pageNotFoundComponent is loaded

Comment: Many thanks. I tried `{
  path: 'home',
  loadChildren: './About/about.module.ts#AboutModule'
 }`, `{
  path: 'home',
  loadChildren: './About/about.module#AboutModule'
 }`, and also `{
  path: 'home',
  component: AboutComponent
 }` but unfortunately none of those worked.

Comment: Sorry, I also needed to change the `about-routing.module.ts` path to: `{path: '', component: AboutComponent}` instead of the previous `{path: 'home', component: AboutComponent}`. After that change, it works great. Many thanks!

Comment: One small issue before I mark this as `Answer` . . . After the redirect, the URL doesn't change (it's still `localhost:4200`, rather than `localhost:4200/home/`). Any ideas how to fix this so that the URL changes to `localhost:4200/home/`?

Comment: OK. It turns out I had the `signup` path defined in both `AppModule` and `AuthRoutingModule`. I believe that probably caused the strange behavior I witnessed, and after removing `signup` path in `AppModule` everything works great now.

Comment: But one final comment. While @Ravi Teja's method works great (I believe it's lazy loading), I didn't need to use that approach. I used a "simpler" approach, with just: `const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '' , redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
  
];` (in `AppRoutingModule`) & `const aboutRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'home', component: AboutComponent}` in feature module (in `AboutRoutingModule`)
];

Comment: A project can have multiple child routes, to separate child routes from the main component, the above method is used. But for loading AboutComponent directly you can use the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

the problme is the

> order

of your routing defintion array .. try this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {path: '' , redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'}, // as first
 {path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
 {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent} // always as last

];
```